# I am using phpmailer and passing body simple text message without html.Then mail send create double line breaks

Tags: phpmailer

I am using phpmailer and passing body simple text message without html.Then mail send create double line breaks. But my content have one line break, please help its perfect on localhost but on server create error.

Comment: post your code here otherwise we can't

Comment: running on the server creating double line break or error ? need some clarity

Comment: $mail->setFrom($mailfrom, $sendername);
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->addAddress($tmpemailaddress);
    $mail->isHTML(false);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;

Comment: $message="hello,<Next line> this mail is regarding for ".   create double break line

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit your question.